# Who is the rapist in the first scene of American Horror Story: Hotel?

Tags: american-horror-story

In American Horror Story: Hotel, Episode 1, we see a deformed figure rape a junkie in front of Hypodermic Sally. This seemed to be a semi-important part of the episode and perhaps the whole season, but thus far, it has not been revealed who this was, what they had to do with the entire plot, and their relation to Sally and the Ten Commandments Killer as well as part of the Hotel Cortez. Who is this and why did Ryan Murphy put this "character" in episode one? Why did they do this and what is the importance of this in terms of the plot? It has not been revealed and I was curious as to what people thought of this quite horrendous scene. Very few characters and scenes are "by accident." I'd like any fan input.

Comment: *"thus far"* So have you watched all the episodes? (Also, the season isn't over until next week...)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this interview with EW](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/08/28/american-horror-story-most-disturbing-scene) it is called the Addiction Demon as Ryan Murphy (co-creator of the show) says "“He is a representation of that and what people go through fighting addiction.” Since both Sally and Gabriel (the victim) in that scene are drug addicts, the rape of Gabriel can be seen as a metaphor for what the drugs are doing to him. My guess is that Sally sees the Demon often (though it's not shown directly in the show).